# Need to Open MDF file in MS Office 365 Access

Tags: sql, sql-server, database, ms-access-2013

I found links to this topic on this and other sites but have had no luck. I know a lot of code but I am REALLY out of my wheelhouse here so please provide very specific instructions if possible.

I would like to import this SQL Server `.MDF` database file (200 MB) into Access tables (or link to the external SQL Server tables, so that I can transfer the data within Access).

I installed SQL Server Management Studio (thought I needed to) but cannot figure out how to get it to connect to the DB... then I think I would need to use the external data ODBC option in access to connect from there but I haven't been able to get anything to work...

This is a one-time need so any creative workaround would be acceptable also...

Any help that you can provide would be greatly appreciated. Thanks!!

Comment: If you already have a `.mdf` floating around on disk, and SQL Server Mgmt Studio installed, you need to go to `Object Explorer > Databases` and then right-click and pick `Attach...` to **attach** the `.mdf` file to your SQL Server instance.

Answer (score 0):

Install SQL Server Express With Tools (2012 should be fine).
When you install this, include the following features:
Database Engine and Management Tools - Basic.

Once you have this installed, open SQL Server Management Studio (Run > ssms.exe).

As marc_s said, you'll need to attach the .MDF file to your SQL Server.
I usually copy the MDF file to C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\MSSQL11.SQLEXPRESS\MSSQL\DATA so when I attach the database, it's the first folder that's open.

Next, in Access 2013, use the Data Import wizard to connect to SQL Server.  You'll need to enter the SQL Server name and instance, usually "localhost\SQLExpress" works for a default SQL Express install.

Follow the Wizard, and it'll allow you to pick which tables/views you want to use.

You can also do this in Excel first, then save the data as .csv or something similar, then import the CSV into Access.